# Why does my functions gets recognized as an Object when using an arrow function inside it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using a `find()` with an arrow function in an method which I'm passing to a child component as a prop. The method works just one time. I'm getting an `Invalid Prop` warning. The second time the method is not executed anymore.

```
vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "selectFkt". Expected Function, got Object 

found in

---> <CompareView> at src/components/customComponents/compareView.vue
       <ElementConfigurator> at src/components/customInputs/ownAwesomeInputs/elementConfigurator.vue
         <Baustoffassistent> at src/components/SmartBrick/Baustoffassistent.vue
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

```js
selectArticle(article) {
      this.selectArticle = article;
      var elementID = this.selectedelement.id;
      this.selectArticle.elementID = elementID;

      var element = this.elements.find(el => el.id === elementID);
      element.artSelected = true;
}
```

Does someone have any solution for this problem? Would be glad with any help.

Comment: Could you add the code where you pass the prop selectFkt? This error message doesn’t seem to be related to the code you posted.

Comment: This is where i pass the select function 
 `<elementArticleCards
                :element="element"
                :addFkt="addToCompareList"
                :removeFkt="removeFromCompareList"
                :selectFkt="selectArticle"
              />`
this is where i defined the props 
`props: {
    element: Object,
    addFkt: Function,
    removeFkt: Function,
    selectFkt: Function
  }`

and this is the function call: <br/>
                  `<v-btn color="#587E5B" @click="selectFkt(article)" class="white--text">Select</v-btn>`

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
this.selectArticle = article;
```

You are replacing the component method with an object. Maybe you wanted to assign article to `this.selectedArticle`?

Comment: Yeah that was what i wanted to do :D . Thank you verry mouch